# TYPO3 Extension DCE giving permission error

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I have installed the extension *DCE* in TYPO3 6.2, and whenever I click on the "Go to List View" button" on the first screen for the DCE UI, I get an error "Invalid form/module token detected. Access Denied!"

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using the Extension "extension builder" after submitting a form in 6.2. The development version fixed it. Maybe you find the answer to the "why" in their repository. I just know, that it has something to do with a new backend security feature in 6.2.